# __FUNC__ undefined in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, msvc12

[image]

I knew `__FUNC__` is predefined macro, but when come to vscode it can not recognize `__FUNC__`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019

Which setting should I need to change or modify?

Comment: If it isn't recognised, then perhaps it isn't a predefined macro.

Comment: But it is recognized by visual c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `__func__`, not `__FUNC__`. If you’re on gcc or clang and the goal is to get readable output you can use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` instead which yields better results (such as actually working for template functions).

Comment: And, so there is no doubt, those macros start and end with **two** underscores. The macro in the title only has one in each place. (In the C++ standard there's a small space between the underscores to make it clear that there are two; normal typesetting doesn't make that prominent enough, as you can see in the text throughout this question and answer)

Comment: @PeteBecker In the font I'm using they look pretty distinct.

Comment: Good point. In the browser that I'm using they run together.

Comment: I forgot to mention I use visual studio c++.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Edit c_cpp_properties.json temporarily solve my problem

I only use VScode as editor not IDE for compiling.

Because Visual 2008's style is not good for my eye...

Comment: why do you use VS2008 in this era?

Comment: I am working for some very old games .....  They need old compiler such as vc2008.